# Dynamic buffer in objective C (with ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, buffer

I'm trying to use the `- (void)getCharacters:(unichar *)buffer range:(NSRange)aRange` method of a `NSString` object but I have an issue with the first parameter.
The number of characters in this NSString is not fixed so I need to allocate my buffer dynamicly (the size of the buffer must be something like `[my_string length] * sizeof(UniChar)`).

I'm new in objective C and don't know how to do that.
Can I use `malloc`(ARC is enabled) like in C program ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can `malloc()` a buffer of the appropriate size. You have to `free()` the buffer
when it is no longer used, because ARC does not manage `malloc`ed memory.

Alternatively, create an `NSData` object with the UTF-16 encoding:

```
NSString *string = @"H€llö Wörld";
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
const unichar *charsPtr = [data bytes];
```

`charsPtr` is valid as long as `data` exists, i.e. as long as you keep a strong reference to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By curiosity, is the second solution better than the first one, or the two solutions are equal ?

Comment: @Morniak: I think that is only a matter of taste. There is a tiny overhead in the second solution because it creates an object. But I like it because you don't have to calculate the buffer size in advance.